# I want to transform xml into html and save the html. What is the easiest way?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I would like to use an xml file to create a html email. I can create an xsl file to convert it to html but I don't know how I can then save or copy the generated html. Obviously if I view the source of the xml file I just get the xml source, not the transformed html. What is the simplest or quickest way possible without me having to use Java or C# or anything like that? Is there a web service that can do it? I've googled but with no luck.

**EDIT**

If I have to do a bit of coding to do this then I could probably manage it in php, javascript, java, vbscript or possibly python. I'd be surprised if a tool to easily do what I want hasn't already been created and made available publicly though.

**EDIT 2** - Solution found

I've discovered that clicking 'View generated source' in the Web Developer toolbar of Firefox shows me the html. This is all I need, I can then copy and paste this. I'd still be interested to hear if anyone has any better suggestions though...

Comment: How are you going to perform the transform? Most xslt processor provide means to save the generated file somewhere.

Comment: At the moment I'm literally just using the browser. If I need something else what is the easiest/quickest/cheapest option? I can write a bit of php/java/javascript/python but I would rather not have to roll my own solution.

Comment: This is usually done by a .xsl transform. You can use any tool to perform the transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably need is an XSLT-Processor.

On most Linux machines xsltproc should be available at the commandline (or be easily installed with 'sudo apt-get install xsltproc').

On Windows [msxsl](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21714) should be the right commandline tool (I didn't test it).

Comment: Thank you, that is more along the lines of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a WinForms app and drop a [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control on it, though I'm not sure if that will let you save the rendered page without any user interaction.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no experience of .NET :[